# Unity iOS support, installation failed

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Unity to create an iOS app. I used Unity Hub to install Unity. I then opened Unity, went to File-Build Settings. I click on iOS, and it says "No iOS module loaded", so I clicked on the "Open Download page". I downloaded **UnitySetup-iOS-Support-for-Editor-2018.4.7f1** and ran it. It looks like everything is going smoothly, and right at the end I get the message in the attached screen shot.

[image]

I have tried closing Xcode and Unity. I have tried restarting my computer. I have done several Google searches, but I haven't found anything that helps. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suspect the installation path got messed up.

You have to use the Unity Hub to install additional packages. 
Go to `Installs`, click the 3 vertical dots and select `Add Modules`.

[image: Unity Hub/ Add Modules]

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok this actually worked for me. Wish Unity actually mentions this as opposed to making us download and install modules manually.

Comment: had same issue with tvOS support and this fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: My Unity hub has only two options for 2018.4.0f1: Reveal in finder, and remove from HUD

Comment: @JoshGraham Did you manually add the Unity-Installation to the Hub?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with tvOS support and it seems that if you don’t have Unity installed to `/Applications/Unity`, [installing addons will fail](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-install-ios-build-support.395608/#post-3140717). (I had it in /Applications/Unity-2019.4.7f1.)

I moved my Unity to `/Applications/Unity`, installed the addon, and then moved Unity back.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me.
However, what did the job (Unity 2018, Unityhub 3.4.1) was copying the installed /Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines to the current /Applications/Unity-[2018....]/PlaybackEngines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).